# Match regex in ksh

Tags: shell-script, scripting, regular-expression, ksh

I am looking to do something like this in KSH:

```
if (( $var = (foo|bar)[0-9]*$ )); then
    print "variable matched regex"
fi
```

Is it possible at all?

For the record I'm using Ksh `Version M-11/16/88i` on a Solaris 10 machine.

Comment: Do you realize the regular expression `[foo|bar]` means "match a single character from the set (a,b,f,o,r,|)"? If you mean "match 'foo' or 'bar'" you want `(foo|bar)`

Comment: True, didn't notice that. I will update accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ksh has regular expressions, but not in the usual syntax (not in [the version in Solaris 10](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9j0/index.html)).

```
if [[ $var = *@(foo|bar)*([0-9]) ]]; then …
```

In the [manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9j0/index.html), look under “conditional expressions” for what's inside the brackets and under “file name generation” for the pattern syntax.

Comment: This is a pattern match, not a regular expression match (which uses the `=~` operator).

Comment: @chepner It doesn't use [regex syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended), but it is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Ksh patterns include all regular expression operators.

Comment: what does the `*@` in the regular expression stands for ?

Comment: @Ali In the ksh regular expression syntax (which is not the usual regex syntax), `*` stands for any sequence of characters and `@(foo|bar)` matches either `foo` or `bar`.

Comment: In this case, the `*([0-9])` says to match zero or more occurrences of what is in the parens, _NOT_ any sequence of characters.  Observe, the regexp will not pass `var="bar##3"`. Meanwhile, it will pass `var` if we have to have zero or more digits. as in `var="bar321"`

Answer (score 4):

Using `case` with glob patterns might work for you. 
The composite pattern `*(pattern-list)` means "Matches  zero  or  more  occurrences  of   the   given patterns" and `@(pattern-list)` means "Matches exactly one of the given patterns."

```
matcher() {
  typeset var="$1"
  case "$var" in
    *@(foo|bar)*([0-9])) print "$var matched" ;;
    *) print "$var did not match" ;;
  esac
}

for var in foo bar baz foo123 abc_foo132 abc_foo123z bar1 1bar1 1bar1a; do 
  matcher "$var"
done
```

Outputs:

```
foo matched
bar matched
baz did not match
foo123 matched
abc_foo132 matched
abc_foo123z did not match
bar1 matched
1bar1 matched
1bar1a did not match
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use *egrep(1)*? Gives you all a regex user could wish for:

```
 if echo "$var" | egrep -s '(foo|bar)[0-9]*$'    # -s means "silent"
  then
    ...
```

Additional note for Solaris: With Solaris you may want to check the manpage for *egrep* - there is annother *egrep* version that is located at `/usr/xpg4/bin/egrep` that supports some more options and differs in functionality when it comes to advanced regex stuff.

Comment: sometimes Solaris will have GNU Egrep installed as well, as gegrep.  Either from the Companion CD, or from SunFreeWare, and usually in /opt/sfw/bin or /usr/local/bin.

Comment: @Tim: true, but I'd never rely on that. From my experience with customer production systems you'd better stick to what the base OS provides since what we would consider cool and helpful is often not allowed in production. +1 anyway ;-)

Comment: 100% agreed.  i try to always use scripts/programs/perl modules that are installed by default.  keeps things portable.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this, using `sed`. I don't know how good it is, but at least it worked ^^

```
if [ -z "$(echo "$var" | sed -e 's/(foo|bar)[0-9]*$//')" ]; then
    print "variable matched regex"
fi
```

Comment: You need to put double quotes around variable substitutions, as always (otherwise you'll get wrong results or errors on some inputs containing wildcard characters or whitespace). Even with the right quoting, this assumes that the input doesn't contain a newline. Furthermore, your method is highly convoluted; [`grep` is more natural](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22977), but [there's a way that's built into ksh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22997).

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but instead of ktf's solution:

```
 if echo "$var" | egrep -s '(foo|bar)[0-9]*$'    # -s means "silent"
  then
    ...
```

you may also use

```
 if grep -q '(foo|bar)[0-9]*$' <<< "$var"        # -q means "quiet" ;-)
  then
    ...
```

This technique with the `<<<` operator is called the *herestring*. However, I should also add a **warning**: this WON'T work under a read-only environment (i. e. you will get ugly error messages to `stderr`), since the herestring requires a temporary file to be written to somewhere. As far as I know, the "classic" way with `echo` and a pipe will also work without any write permission at all.